# What impact would a domain rename have on Azure AD sync?

Tags: active-directory, azure, rename

We have a local AD domain which syncs up to Azure. We recently decided we want to rename this domain and I am unsure what impact this will have on Azure. The domain rename doesn't change the GUID, so does that mean Azure will hook back up to the domain again without issue? I don't want it to treat it as a new directory entirely and end up losing the users' data.

Comment: This is a question probably best posed to Microsoft support.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it in my lab. After renaming the AD Domain name, AAD connect doesn't work. I get the error message below:

[image]

Also, Domain name renaming is error prone. As a workaround, we are able to use the UPN suffix to allow users to login with a different domain name.